# Quartz.net Cron schedule that fires the first Saturday of every month

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz.net 3.0.  How do I create a Cron schedule that fires the first Saturday of every month at 1 am?

Comment: That's good. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe SATL will schedule the last Saturday of the month.   Will SATF schedule for the first Saturday of the month?

Comment: Using "0 35 12 ? * MONL *" worked.  It fired at 12:35 today.

Comment: I was hoping this would trigger on the first Wednesday of the month at 1 am, but it did not: .WithCronSchedule("0 0 1 ? * WEDF *")   I guess F doesn't mean First.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is checking this post with other variations of this cron schedule use http://www.cronmaker.com. For this question I got `0 0 1 ? 1/1 SAT#1 *` which I tested and it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a few months old, but in case you haven't already figured it out
"0 1 0 ? * SAT#1" should do the trick.

From the tutorial:
The ‘#’ is used to specify “the nth” XXX weekday of the month.

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html

Comment: I used "0 0 1 ? * SATL *"